# Difference between Scopes and Namespaces in python?

Tags: python

I am new in python, please describe difference between Scopes and Namespaces with example.

thanks in advance

Comment: My first reaction was the same as @Shashank.  So I did google it to see what turns up in the first few results.  Two related questions from programmers.stackexchange and stackoverflow are returned in the top three results. So while it's an easily google-able question I don't think it warrants any '-1's.

Answer (score 14):

## Scopes

You can think of "scope" as being the set of names that you have access to from a particular point in the code.

```
x = 1
y = 2
def foo():
  z = 3 + y

# Here, I have access to `x, y, foo` -- They are in the current scope
# `z` is not in the current scope.  It is in the scope of `foo`.
a = x + y
b = x + z  # NameError because `z` is not in my scope.
```

Note that within the function `foo`, I have access to the "enclosing" scope.  I can *read* from any name that is defined inside the function, but also any name that is defined in the environment where my function was created.

In the example, inside the function of `foo`, the scope contains `x`, `y`, `foo`, `z`, and `a` (it would contain `b` if `b` were to get defined and not throw the `NameError`).

```
 ______________________________
 |                            |
 |   Names in enclosing scope |
 |      {x, y, foo, ...}      |
 |                            |
 |   --------------------     |
 |   | function scope   |     |
 |   |       {z}        |     |
 |   | (Also has access |     |
 |   | enclosing scope) |     |
 |   --------------------     |
 |                            |
 ------------------------------
```

---

## Namespaces

A namespace is a related concept.  It is generally thought of as an object that holds a set of names.  You can then access the names (and the data they reference) by looking at the members of the object.

```
foo.x = 1
foo.y = 2
foo.z = 3
```

Here, `foo` is a namespace.  I suppose you can think of a namespace as a container of names.  The most natural unit of namespace in python is a `module` though a `class`, instance of a class, function *can* be a namespace since you can attach arbitrary names/data to them under most circumstances.

Note that in python, these concepts become a little jumbled as you can import a module's scope *as a namespace*

```
# foo.py
x = 1
y = 1

# bar.py
import foo
print foo.x
print foo.y
```

Note that the "global" scope of `foo` gets imported into the global scope of `bar` as the namespace `foo` in this example.

We can also import the global scope of `foo` into the global scope of `bar` without a namespace if we want (though this practice is generally discouraged):

```
# bar.py
from foo import *
print x
print y
```